# Discord.py different cooldown per user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make a command that have only a cooldown if the user is not in a list
This is my code:

```
@commands.command(name='cooldown')
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def cdown(self, ctx):
  await ctx.send("Executed")
```

And this is how it should be:

```
@commands.command(name='cooldown')
if not user in no_cooldown_users:
  @commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def cdown(self, ctx):
  await ctx.send("Executed")
```

Is there any possibility to make this instead of using a config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a custom cooldown, here a very simple example

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class CustomCooldown:
    def __init__(self, rate, per, alter_rate, alter_per, bucket, *, elements):
        self.elements = elements
        # Default mapping is the default cooldown
        self.default_mapping = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(rate, per, bucket)
        # Alter mapping is the alternative cooldown
        self.alter_mapping = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(alter_rate, alter_per, bucket)
        # Copy of the original BucketType
        self._bucket_type = bucket

    def __call__(self, ctx):
        key = self.alter_mapping._bucket_key(ctx.message)

        if self._bucket_type is commands.BucketType.member: # `BucketType.member` returns a tuple
            key = key[1] # The second (last) value is the member ID, the first one is the guild ID

        if key in self.elements:
            # If the key is in the elements, the bucket will be taken from the alternative cooldown
            bucket = self.alter_mapping.get_bucket(ctx.message)
        else:
            # If not, from the default cooldown
            bucket = self.default_mapping.get_bucket(ctx.message)

        # Getting the ratelimit left (can be None)
        retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()

        if retry_after: # If the command is on cooldown, raising the error
            raise commands.CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)
        return True
```

To use it:

```py
@command.commands()
@commands.check(CustomCooldown(1, 300, 1, 0, commands.BucketType.user, elements=[list of ids]))
async def foo(self, ctx):
    ...
```

The first two values are the rate and per of the default cooldown, the next two values are for the "special" cooldown. Next there's the bucket type, and lastly the list of elements (ids).

You can also use this method for different cooldown per roles/guilds/categories/channels...