# discord.py How to make different jobs with different cooldowns work under !work command

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases = ["Work", "w", "W"]) 
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await getbankdata()

    user = ctx.author

    job = users[str(user.id)]["job"]

    if job == None:
        await ctx.send(f"You have no job! Type !jobs for list of jobs and !getjob *jobname* to get a job.")
    elif job == "youtuber":
        await youtuberwork(ctx, ctx.author)
    elif job == "manager":
        await managerwork(ctx, ctx.author)
    elif job == "receptionist":
        await receptionistwork(ctx, ctx.author)






@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
@cooldown(1, 18000, BucketType.user)
async def youtuberwork(ctx, user):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author

    users = await getbankdata()

    earnings = 120

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    await ctx.send(f"You Worked as a YouTuber and gained {earnings} coins!")

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)






@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
@cooldown(1, 19800, BucketType.user)
async def managerwork(ctx, user):

    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await getbankdata()

    earnings = 150

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    await ctx.send(f"You Worked as a Manager and gained {earnings} coins!")

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)



@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
@cooldown(1, 16200, BucketType.user)
async def receptionistwork(ctx, user):

    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await getbankdata()

    earnings = 100

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    await ctx.send(f"You Worked as a Receptionist and gained {earnings} coins!")

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Hi guys! So i want to make different jobs work with different cooldowns work under !work command. The code i gave above doesn't work. To be more spesific cooldown doesn't work. It will do other stuff it is supposed to do (give money to user and send a message in the channel). I tried to fix this for weeks now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py different cooldown per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581190/discord-py-different-cooldown-per-user)

Comment: no it doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it's pretty clear why it doesn't work.
So, when user runs a command !work, depending on their work it runs the function that is responsible for the working. Unfortunately, because the user is actually only runing the `work` function, not `youtuberwork` the cooldown for the `youtuberwork` is not applied. (the function the user ran ran the youtuberwork, not the user, it would work if user wouldn't use !work but !youtuberwork etc...)

Unfortunately, I can't help you with your code that you have now, I am not entirely sure how it would be possible for the cooldown to be ran, but what you can do is make it so the user must run the actuall command responsible for the user working.

An alternative to the previous "solution" would be to add a check in the work function - if ctx.author has worked in the last X amount of seconds, pass, otherwise run the function.
Altough, I don't recommend doing so, I really do not have an adequate answer that could help you with this.

As mentioned, the best solution I have would be to just make the user run the actual command, makes it much simpler.