# discord.py bot commands - how to make different cooldown times for different users

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a discord bot that has a different cooldown time for every user for the same command. For example, when user 1 !works, their cooldown is 5 seconds whereas user 2 has a cooldown of 6 seconds when they !work. Reading the docs for the cooldown decorator, there doesn't seem to be a way to have multiple cooldowns. This method does not work because I get an error since ctx hasn't been defined and I have no way of getting user data before the function definition.  How would I set this up so that I can have a variable cooldown for each user?

```
def fetch(self, username, column):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT %s FROM users WHERE username=?" %column, (username,))
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

#the call to fetch should theoretically return the cooldown for that user
@commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=fetch(str(ctx.message.author), cooldown), type=commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command(name='example')
async def example(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello")
```

Comment: btw `per` should be a `float`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py different cooldown per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581190/discord-py-different-cooldown-per-user)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to have your bot create a number of unique cooldowns that is only known at runtime. In this case, it might be easier to use [`Command.add_check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands#discord.ext.commands.Command.add_check) than the cooldown decorator.

If your code is in a class that inherits `commands.Cog`, then maybe something like this would meet your needs:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.cooldowns = dict()
    works_command = self.bot.get_command('works')
    works_command.add_check(check_cooldown)


async def initialize_cooldowns(self):  # This function still needs to be called somewhere.
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        user_id = row['user_id']
        duration = row['duration']
        self.cooldowns[user_id] = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, duration, commands.BucketType.user)
            

async def check_cooldown(self, ctx):
    row = my_fetchrow(ctx.author)  # my_fetchrow gets one row of a table; not defined here.
    user_id = row['user_id']
    bucket = self.cooldowns[user_id].get_bucket(ctx.message)

    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    if retry_after:
        raise commands.CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)
    return True
```

If `initialize_cooldowns` doesn't need to be async, you can call it in `__init__`.

Otherwise, you will probably want to use `self.bot.loop.create_task`, e.g.

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.cooldowns = dict()
    self._task = self.bot.loop.create_task(self.initialize_cooldowns())
    works_command = self.bot.get_command('works')
    works_command.add_check(check_cooldown)


async def initialize_cooldowns(self):
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    ...
```

In these examples, `initialize_cooldowns` runs when the bot starts and creates a cooldown for each user that you already saved information about. You may also want to create a way to add more keys to the cooldowns dictionary while the bot is running, and use a try/except block for KeyErrors in `check_cooldown`.