# Discord.py Select Menu Cooldown

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a cooldown to my select menu that I'm using to select different categories for opening tickets. This is my code so far:

```py
import discord, json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
import time
from variables import ticketData, ticketSetup, closeTicket

class panelSelect(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Questions",emoji="❓",description="Any questions you would like to ask the staff team."),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Applying for Roles",emoji="✨",description="Apply for some roles like YouTuber or Godbridger."),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Report",emoji="",description="Report a member in the server for breaking rules."), 
          discord.SelectOption(label="Others",emoji="⚠️",description="Any other reasons for opening a ticket.")
            ]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Select a ticket category...",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options, custom_id="selectTicketTypeView")
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        interaction.message.author = interaction.user
        bucket = self.cooldown.get_bucket(interaction.message)
        retry = bucket.update_rate_limit()
        if retry:
          return await interaction.response.send_message(f"Slow down! Try again in {round(retry, 1)} seconds.", ephemeral = True)
        if self.values[0] == "Questions":
          
          await ticketSetup(
            interaction=interaction,
            fields=["1. What is your question?|Explain your question, in detail, while waiting for a staff member arrives."])
          
        elif self.values[0] == "Applying for Roles":
          
          await ticketSetup(
            interaction=interaction,
            fields=["1. What role would you like to apply for?|What role are you aiming to get?","2. Proof|If this applies to your role, what is the proof that you would be eligible for the role?"])

        elif self.values[0] == "Report":

          await ticketSetup(
            interaction=interaction,
            fields=["Who are you reporting?|Please mention the member you are reporting.","What rule did they break?|Which rule did the member break in <#735346274886483988>?","Provide some proof.|Give us a screenshot, jump url or any sufficient proof that proves that they broke a rule. "])

        elif self.values[0] == "Others": 
                  await ticketSetup(
            interaction=interaction,
            fields=["Why did you open this ticket?|You selected the `Others` category so please explain your query."])
          
class panelSelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = None):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.add_item(panelSelect())
        self.cooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.member)
```

This code works perfectly without the first 5 lines of the asyncronous function "callback" and without the 4th line of the class "panelSelectView"

Later on in the `Cogs.tickets` cog, this is the line I use to pass the view. I'm also using the setup hook method in `main.py` to keep it persistent.

```py
        message = await channel.send(embed=embed, view=panelSelectView(timeout=None))
```

This is the error I get

```
[31mTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/REDACTED/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/REDACTED/Cogs/tickets.py", line 18, in callback
    bucket = self.cooldown.get_bucket(interaction.message)
AttributeError: 'panelSelect' object has no attribute 'cooldown'
```

This is for a ticketing system by the way. Thanks,

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. You could disable the view for a few seconds or sleep until you do/allow the next action.

Comment: ellaborate please

Comment: After selecting, so the callback gets triggered, you can disable the view and do your updates or whatever you want to achieve with the cooldown itself OR after selecting you `asyncio.sleep()` for a certain amount of time until the code does the next step.

Comment: I see, so can I not make the bot give an error discord message whenever someone breaks the cooldown

Comment: `'panelSelect' object has no attribute 'cooldown'` - No

Comment: I see `self.cooldown` in the callback, but you never define `cooldown`. I'm having a hard time following the code because I don't see self.cooldown anywhere and that's what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, since I had to come up with some of my own code to make it work for me, but I think your main issue is that the cooldown property is in the wrong class, it should be in `panelSelect` not `panelSelectView`.

Unfortunately, even with this change I couldn't get the code you were trying to use to work at all. It seems that `bucket.update_rate_limit()` doesn't properly effect the rate limit and instead returns None, unless the `tokens=` is not 1, in which case it will always return 60.0 from my testing.

I used `@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)` above my bot command, which seems to be what you want to achieve, and you can view the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.cooldown), and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66581525/11072533) question you can make more complex rate systems but I didn't test that out myself. I this isn't what you need then I'm not really sure how much more I can help, since I'm not sure how to make your version work properly.

Comment if you have any questions, and the code I used to make this work is below (command is `+menu`)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class panelSelect(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="Questions", emoji="❓",
                                 description="Any questions you would like to ask the staff team."),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Applying for Roles", emoji="✨",
                                 description="Apply for some roles like YouTuber or Godbridger."),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Report", emoji="",
                                 description="Report a member in the server for breaking rules."),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Others", emoji="⚠️", description="Any other reasons for opening a ticket.")
        ]
        self.cooldown: commands.CooldownMapping = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.member)
        super().__init__(placeholder="Select a ticket category...", max_values=1, min_values=1, options=options,
                         custom_id="selectTicketTypeView")

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print(interaction)
        # I don't know how to respond to interactions


class panelSelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=None):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.add_item(panelSelect())
        self.cooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.member)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f'This command is on a {error.retry_after:.2f}s cooldown', ephemeral=True)


@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command()
async def menu(ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context):
   msg = await ctx.send("menu", view=panelSelectView())


bot.run("BOT_TOKEN")
```

Comment: That code is perfect and the reason I got it wrong was because, as you correctly said: "is that the cooldown property is in the wrong class, it should be in panelSelect not panelSelectView" I removed the self.cooldown in panelSelectView and put it above the  line that begins with "super()." and I got the cooldown working. I think the reason why it didn't work for you is beacuse you copied my custom_id but didn't make the view persistent using the setup hook method like I did in main.py . thanks for the help